# Why is grouping operator used in this line of code?

Tags: javascript, express

I was going through `express-session` npm package source code and run across this line of code:

```
// get the session ID from the cookie
var cookieId = (req.sessionID = getcookie(req, name, secrets));
```

Isn't it the same as this line? :

```
// get the session ID from the cookie
var cookieId = req.sessionID = getcookie(req, name, secrets);
```

Why would they do it? Is this a some sort of code style decision or what do I miss ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some linters warn when you don't put parentheses around an `=` expression, due to people commonly typing `=` when they mean to type `==`. The parentheses around the expression tells the linter that it's an intentional decision. Otherwise, the two lines are semantically equivalent.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be a case in this code base because they have something like this too:  `exports = module.exports = session;`

Comment: @Noob perhaps the author of the code missed that line, or perhaps the author doesn't use a linter, and just thinks you need the `()` when dealing with a function ... really, the only person that would know why they use `()` in one place but not the other is the author of the code :p

Comment: @JaromandaX  thanks, just wanted to make sure that I didn't misunderstand  anything.

Comment: This is correct. Assignations are always computed right to left, parentheses here only make difference to linting, not execution.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be stylistic choices, especially since it makes it clear that the single `=` is intentional and not a typo for `==` or `===`

```js
foo = bar = 5;
faz = (baz = 5);

console.log({foo, bar});
console.log({faz, baz});
```